# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - receiving a startup error of System.ExecutionEngineException

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I recently installed VS2010 Ultimate on my Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit Edition computer and I receive "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" randomly (or so it seems) when starting the IDE.  If I reboot the computer then about 50% of the time the IDE will start normally.  If not, I have to keep rebooting until it finally behaves normally.

I've looked around on various sites and this seems like an error that comes from many different problems ... any idea on why I might be receiving it, or something I should be checking for?

Thanks for any help or advice you care to offer.

Comment: Which extensions/add-ons/languages have you installed on Visual Studio?

Comment: It's "stock."  Nothing new added.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the system event log? There might be some clues there. You can also try a couple of the [VS command line parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx) such as [Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx), [SafeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx), [ResetSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx).

Another approach which is more advanced and not for the faint of heart is to use [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) to start devenv.exe from WinDbg to see what causes the crash by looking at what threads are doing (stack trace, etc.).